# Python Polars: How to skip empty line in the CSV file using pl.scan()

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Python Polars: How to skip empty line in the CSV file using `pl.scan()`?

```py
df=pl.scan_csv('c:/test.tab', separator='\t', skip_rows=2)

print(df)
```

`c:/test.tab` **(delimiter is tab space)**

```
row1 : V5 test file
row2 : 
row3 : Date filename    count
row4 : 16-FEB-23    test123.csv 120
row5 : 17-FEB-23    sample111.csv   100
row6 : 18-FEB-23    abcd12.csv  12
```

Issue:

1. It was skipping the row4 and produce row5 & row6 only when we use `skip_rows=2`.
2. However tried to use `skip_rows=1` then It does not recognize the columns at row3 because it checking at row2 as header.

Comment: Could not reproduce your error. 'skip_rows=2' worked fine for me. Are you on last version? You can always not skip any rows, then skip rows later and rename columns

Answer (score 0):

To skip empty lines while reading a CSV file using `pl.scan_csv()` in polars, you can create a function for empty lines. Not sure but this might give you a hint I guess?

```
import polars as pl

   def skip_empty_lines(row):
      return not all(value == "" for value in row)
```

Or something Like this?
It would be easier for all NULL rows.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `pl.LazyFrame.filter` to skip rows that do not satisfy a condition.  We want the predicate function to evaluate to true if any of the values in the row are not null.

With the help of the builtin `functools` and `operator` libraries, you can achieve this declaratively.

```py
df = (
    (df := pl.scan_csv('c:/test.tab', separator='\t'))
    .filter(
        ~functools.reduce(
            operator.or_,
            map(lambda col: pl.col(col).is_null(), df.columns))))
```

We map the column names into `pl.col` expressions, and invoke the `is_null` method.  The `functools.reduce` folds the `operator.or_` horizontally.